# How do you heal Permanent Injuries without powers?

Tags: savage-worlds, healing

In Savage Worlds, when a character is rendered Incapacitated, they have a chance of acquiring a Permanent Injury. This is some kind of disfigurement that provides a permanent penalty to the character, which usually ends up being a permanent reduction to an attribute.

In a game with magic, there is a Greater Healing power that allows players to heal their Permanent Injuries, but there doesn't appear to be a non-magical equivalent.

If I'm playing in a game without any form of healing magic, is there a way to heal Permanent Injuries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If I'm playing in a game without any form of healing magic, is there a way to heal Permanent Injuries?

Depends upon the setting.

- **Pre-Modern** societies have no non-magic option to remove permanent injuries. Peg legs, hook hands, eye patches, and similar tools are the only options.
- **Modern** settings, similar to real life, have no option to heal permanent injuries; just physical therapy (spending an Advance to increase the damaged Attribute), prosthetic limbs (in the case of One Leg or One Arm) that are inferior to the original limb, and cosmetic surgery to reduce the scarring (Ugly).
- **Science Fiction** settings often have some kind of "miraculous medicine" that could be applied. Clone replacement, nano machines, cybernetics, quantum reconstruction, or whatever else fits the medical technology of the setting.

Since being able to heal a permanent injury is a **Setting Rule**, the setting creator will need to define the associated game mechanics. 
 The mechanics of the *greater healing* power are a useful guideline (roll at -4) for such rules; rejection of [technique] is an excellent explanation for why a particular character cannot be healed by a failed check, if you choose to keep the "it's really permanent" result.

Without a setting rule and without the *greater healing* power, permanent injuries are truly permanent.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer: you don't.  That's why they're "Permanent" injuries.

Don't forget, however, that as GM, you might allow a setting-appropriate way around this.  In Deadlands, your characters might hear of a native shaman who is reputed to be able to heal; in Weird War II, there might be an experimental surgery that stands a chance of repairing the damage (or making it worse, if it's truly experimental).  In a far future setting, it might be easier just to amputate and attach a cybernetic part.

Any of these methods would/should be expensive or hazardous, or both, and they may require figuratively jumping through some hoops before they're available, as opposed to rumored.

Comment: Absolutely. This kind of thing is just ripe for a juicy plot-hook and whole set of adventures